# Elm Reactor not hot swapping

Tags: elm

Using elm-reactor v0.16, hot swapping does not seem to be working.

Even if I...

- clone the samples from https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial
- use the in browser "Try Elm" at http://elm-lang.org/examples

I am using windows and atom, and have run the elm installer. My steps are

1. Clone examples repo (above)
2. in console, cd into /src/examples/1
3. Run "elm-reactor" (have also tried "elm reactor")
4. Load localhost:8000/Main.elm?debug in browser
5. Make a change in either Main.elm or Counter.elm and save the file

The change i made, was to add an input to the Counter view. This compiles and displays if i refresh the page.

I have seen a few issues recently about the reactor not hot swapping, but nothing to say that it is flat out not working.

I have also tried this on several different projects (just mentioned this examples proj as the most simple)

Thanks!

**Update**

Just found this: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/elm-dev/1QC2ywqv0EY/2tNuPFccCAAJ

from 3rd December 2015 - any update on this would be good... althought its worth stressing that i have not seen hot swapping work once - makes me think my setup is suspect.

Comment: what behavior are you expecting?  should the page automatically reload any time you make code changes?  I haven't seen that happen in my setup either, I always have to reload.

Comment: I am expecting at minimum to page to reload. However, accoring to the docs, the individual component should reload. This suggests there are no full page reloads http://elm-lang.org/blog/interactive-programming (checkout the video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the time of this post, it seems that elm reactor is not working at all.

However, there are a number of skeletons on there that make use of gulp, browserSync & the like - to allow file watch and auto reload.

This one worked best for me: https://github.com/simonh1000/elm-fullstack-starter